# Geoserver and ExceptionReport.xsd

Tags: xsd, geoserver

I am having trouble removing access to ExceptionReports.xsd in Geoserver. This is a government site and is currently being tested by a PenTest team.

Even after disabling the Geoserver login page, it is still possible to reach these ExceptionReports.

We are currently on Geoserver version 2.21.5 and this is an example path:

.../geoserver/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd

There are other paths, however the PenTest team feels that these reports are unacceptable so we ned to figure a way to remove any URLs under **geoserver** that result in page info.

Does anyone know of a way to turn off or disable these exception reports?

As I stated earlier, I have removed the ability to reach the Geoserver login page. I still do not know how to remove the ExceptionReport styles sheets from being shown. And if it is actually possible to do so.

Comment: Those are published schemas that are widely available, why do you need to hide them?

Comment: I had asked our PenTest team the exact question. I was told that any URL path that allows public access, is unacceptable. The ISM and ISSO want to disable these schemas from being accessible publicly. So I'm not clear if there is any way to block access or not. :/

Comment: Have you tried disabling service metadata? https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/service-metadata/index.html

Comment: I guess you could use some sort of response filter to replace the local schema references to the official ones (https://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.1.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd) - we only provide a local copy to assist off line servers and to improve bandwidth for clients. But this is still a complete waste of time and classic security theatre